# Join returns duplicate rows

Tags: postgresql

I am learning PostgreSQL using the Sakila database. There's a table called actor that has an `actor_id`, `first_name` and `last_name`. There is another table that has actors mapped to films through an `actor_id` and `film_id` combination.

I expect the following query to return one row for each actor with the maximum value for film_id for that actor, but I am getting multiple rows instead of one (the maximum of film_id for that actor).

```
SELECT actor.first_name, actor.last_name, MAX(film_actor.film_id)
FROM actor
LEFT JOIN film_actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
GROUP BY film_actor.film_id, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
ORDER BY film_actor.film_id;
```

I appreciate your help in understanding how to get this right using joins (I already have the solution to achieve this using a sub-query).

PS: I am sure this question is often asked by beginners to SQL, but I have not seen an answer that works yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove `film_actor.film_id` from:

```
GROUP BY film_actor.film_id, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
```

because you want to group by actor only.
 
So change to this:

```
GROUP BY actor.actor_id, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
```

I added also `actor.actor_id` just in case there are 2 actors with the same name.
and change the `ORDER BY` clause to:

```
ORDER BY MAX(film_actor.film_id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The tweak almost worked. The only thing is that I see only 199 rows instead of 200 that I expected to see. Any thoughts on what's causing this? I am certain that there is a row in film_actor for every actor in the actor table.

Comment: You have a LEFT JOIN so you get all the rows from the table `actor`. If you see 199 rows then there are 199 rows, **OR** is there a case of 2 actors having the same name?

Comment: You are absolutely spot on. There is indeed an actor whose name repeats twice. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: I don't want to be a pain, but I am trying to warp my head around suppressing duplicates from joins. I tried to get the film title by adding another join as below, which returns duplicates (5462 rows): 

`SELECT actor.first_name, actor.last_name, film.title, MAX(film_actor.film_id)
FROM actor LEFT JOIN film_actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
LEFT JOIN film ON film_actor.film_id = film.film_id
GROUP BY actor.actor_id, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
ORDER BY MAX(film_actor.film_id);`

Appreciate your help in removing duplicates from the result.

Comment: If you want the title of the max film id of your current query you must join it as a whole to the table film: `SELECT t.first_name, t.last_name, f.title, t.maxfilmid
FROM (
  SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, MAX(fa.film_id) maxfilmid 
  FROM actor a LEFT JOIN film_actor fa ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id 
  GROUP BY a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name 
) t LEFT JOIN film f ON t.maxfilmid = f.film_id 
ORDER BY t.maxfilmid;` I hope I have no typos.

Comment: That worked. So, there isn't a way in which this can be achieved without the sub-query?

Comment: No because the subquery uses group by to get the max filmid and the result of this grouping must be joined to film to get the film title.

Comment: Ah! I get it now. Thanks a lot once again.